# Load more than 10 items in RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager of 3 span count on first time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, recyclerview-layout, gridlayoutmanager

I using GridLayoutManager with 3 span count in recyclerView on my app, the problem is when I run the app first time it's showing only first 10 items due to the the restriction / pagiation of the items from server, when user refreshing with `SwipeRefreshLayout` or scrolling it's continue loading other items, but it's look ugly on first load of items so I want fill these gaps without necessary for refreshing to load other items

here's the gridlayout with scroll listener

```
gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 3);

 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    isScrolling = true;
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy > 0) {
                        currentItems = gridLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                        totalItems = gridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                        scrollOutItems = gridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems)) {
                        isScrolling = false;
                        if (getItemsByLabelCalled) {
                            for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
                                if (navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).isChecked()) {
                                    getItemsByLabel(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).getTitle().toString());
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            getData();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

SwipeRefreshLayout

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                if (navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).isChecked()) {
                    if (Utils.hasNetworkAccess(MainActivity.this)) {
                        getData();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText
                                (MainActivity.this, R.string.SwipeRefreshLayout_connect_to_update
                                        , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
                        if (navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).isChecked()) {
                            getItemsByLabel(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).getTitle().toString());
                        }
                    }
                }

                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false), 2000);
            }

        });
```

The problem described with images

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am a beginner... But sometimes this helps. [RecyclerView pagination Example](https://androidride.com/android-recyclerview-load-more-on-scroll-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your items count is not enough to fill the entire page. There are two ways to overcome this issue.

1. You can call your `getData` method one more time after loading the first batch to get more data which is not a clean solution since you might need more items on larger screens like tablets.
2. Put your load more procedure in `onBindViewHolder` method of your recycler view adapter instead of its on scroll listener. You can do the load more if `position == getItemCount()-1` for instance which requests server for more items if your last item gets in view (or needs binding). Remember that you have to hold a boolean in order to prevent repetitive calls on your `getData`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the items is more than ten of course, and I tested it with linear layout manager, see the GIF when I refresh its load the other items, the second solution seems good but I cannot call `getData` from my adapter class although it is public

Comment: Of course you have more than 10 items, but each of your batches contains 10. You can create an interface with your desired methods like `getData` and implement it in your activity/fragment (where you declared your method already) and pass and hold a reference to it in your adapter and call the methods whenever you want.